# jQuery ajax request failing in firefox developer edition over HTTPS

Tags: jquery, ajax, https, mixed-content, firefox-developer-edition

I have written a javascript which requests a text to my **http**://localhost/fileread.php and put the response into a textarea in a website with **https**:// connection (`https://translate.google.com/`). Since I'm taking some content from **http** website to a **https** website, firefox doesn't allow me to do so because of the [mixed content policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content). So I turned off the bit for `security.mixed_content.block_active_content` to `false` in `about:config`. Now the normal firefox just gives a warning and allows me to copy the content into that textarea.

But I want to use this script in my [firefox developer edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) because of security reasons. I do the same and allow the mixed content in about:config. But the ajax request to fetch the content from my localhost fails. Here is the code snippet:

```js
function getFileContent(name){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://localhost/fileread.php",
        crossDomain: false,
        data: {"file":name},
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML = responseData;
             //document.getElementById("gt-submit").click();
             DownloadFile(name);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("Ajax request failed");
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

It works in the normal firefox but it fails in the developer edition with errorThrown = undefined. I don't have any idea if it is a problem of jQuery or mixed content. How to get it work in developer edition?

P.S. : The script works fine over **http** websites (`http://www.bing.com/translator`) in both normal and developer edition. Also, it is a valid solution to setup the web server to use **https** in this case, but I tried that and failed miserably. So that's not an option for me.

Comment: Just set your web server up to use `https`

Comment: I tried but failed miserably. I had to install it fresh and don't want to do that again. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What webserver / os are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Apache xampp (phpmyadmin + mysql)

Comment: check out https://letsencrypt.org/     --- there is an automated program available that can simplify the installation of SSL certificates there (and its free) -- this may be your only solution as the web is moving towards a https only future rather rapidly

Comment: tried the certbot to automatically install SSL certificates, but it also failed. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: what exactly is the error your getting from firefox developer edition when you try to access mixed content?

Comment: Also, have you tried remotely interacting with the site over PHP instead of through Javascript? That might work...